# Websocket to download live data in python

Tags: python, websocket

I'm developing a simple program that downloads the order book of the bitstamp webpage using websockets.

The following code subscribes a channel, however, I cannot see the data that is receiving. Do you know why?

The code is the following (and there is an example in javascript [here](https://www.bitstamp.net/s/webapp/examples/order_book_v2.html)):

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json


async def test():
    uri = "wss://ws.bitstamp.net"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        subscribeMsg = {"event": "bts:subscribe", "data": {"channel": "order_book_btcusd"}}

        subscribeMsg = json.dumps(subscribeMsg)

        await websocket.send(subscribeMsg)
        print("subscription message = ", subscribeMsg)

        answer = await websocket.recv()
        print("answer = ", answer)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(test())
loop.run_forever()
```

The output is:

```
subscription message =  {"event": "bts:subscribe", "data": {"channel": "order_book_btcusd"}}
answer =  {"event":"bts:subscription_succeeded","channel":"order_book_btcusd","data":{}}
```

However I expect something with the order book information, like shown in [here]. [1](https://www.bitstamp.net/s/webapp/examples/order_book_v2.html)

Comment: Please add more detail - what output _do_ you get?

Comment: Ok, I just had a small comment about the output.

Comment: So subscription is successful - shouldn’t your code await in the with statement for messages on the subscription (your code closes the websocket)?

Comment: That is the thing that I don't know how to do and the documentation is almost impossible to understand.

Comment: Nothing to lose, why not just try it - start with a `while True:` loop which has just two lines `mesg = await websocket.recv()` and then prints `mesg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, after printing `answer`:

```
   print( “answer=“,answer )
   while True:
       mesg = await websocket.recv()
       print( “mesg=“,mesg )
```